# Need to format number only k(thausand) not m(million) or b(billion) numeraljs

Tags: jquery, numeral.js

We need to format number only **k(thousand)** not m(million) or b(billion) with [numeraljs](http://numeraljs.com/#use-it) currently its converting all formats

```js
var number = 2000000; 
console.log(numeral(number).format('0a'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>
```

Expected result id 2000K Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not real familiar with numeraljs, but I think you may have to create a [custom format](http://numeraljs.com/#custom-formats).

[Demo - codepen](https://codepen.io/jbanegas/pen/BZeOGa?editors=1012)

**Custom Format**

```
numeral.register('format', 'thousands', {
regexps: {
    format: /(k)/,
    unformat: /(k)/
},
format: function(value, format, roundingFunction) {
    var space = numeral._.includes(format, ' k') ? ' ' : '',
        output;

    value = value*.001;

    format = format.replace(/\s?\k/, '');

    output = numeral._.numberToFormat(value, format, roundingFunction);

    if (numeral._.includes(output, ')')) {
        output = output.split('');

        output.splice(-1, 0, space + 'k');

        output = output.join('');
    } else {
        output = output + space + 'k';
    }

    return output;
}
});
```

**Use Format**

```
var number = 2000000; 
console.log(numeral(number).format('0k'));
```